# Tense matching problems, e.g.: “I found out Pat is/was male”

Tags: tense-agreement

Suppose Pat is male. Which one is correct?

> I found out Pat **is** male.
>
> I found out Pat **was** male.

Does the following change make any difference?

> She said Pat **is** male.
>
> She said Pat **was** male.

Suppose you created a mathematical model. When you are describing a result, which one (or neither) is correct?

> The model analysis **shows** that the equilibrium **is** stable.
>
> The model analysis **showed** that the equilibrium **is** stable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either may be correct, in different circumstances.

In speaking of facts about a past event or a dead person, use the past tense:  there is strong semantic dissonance in saying

> <sup>∗</sup> I found out that Shakespeare **is** a male.
>   <sup>∗</sup> She said that the Battle of Borodino **is** fought on September 7.

But when you are speaking of enduring truths—facts which would in immediate discourse be reported with the present tense—you have a choice. Which tense you use will depend on the context: what are you going to do with what was found out or said or shown?

If you are dealing with the present consequences of the discovery/claim/demonstration, you should you use the present tense:

> She said that J.K.Rowling is male, which we all know to be false.
>   Galileo showed that the earth revolves around the sun, which we all take for granted today. <sup>†</sup>

But if what was discovered/claimed/shown is no longer true, or has been shown to be untrue, or if you are narrating what resulted in the past from the discovery/claim/demonstration, you have the option of using the past tense, which may provide your discourse a little more coherence:

> It used to be said that the subject of a gerund clause **had** to be in the possessive case.
>   When as a boy I found out that the author of *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer’s Stone* **was** female I started taking women writers more seriously.
>   Galileo showed that the earth **revolved** around the sun, which excited considerable hostility among theologians.

---

<sup>∗</sup>  *marks a usage as unacceptable*
<sup>†</sup>Thanks to BobRodes for this example.